# Entity Framework Core: how to get the previous record's Id and the next record's Id?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core to get a record from the database, and I need to get the id of the record before and the id of the record after.

This is the code of getting the record:

```
var property = db.properties
              .Include(x => x.category)
              .Include(y => y.subCategory)
              .Include(z => z.SecondSubCategory)
              .Include(e => e.heating)
              .Include(e => e.type)
              .Include(e => e.provience)
              .Include(e => e.city)
              .Include(e => e.street)
              .FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == id);
```

Comment: *Previous* and *Next* indicate an **ordering** - so what are these records supposed to be ordered by?

Comment: ordered by id (property.id)